# Wrapper function for cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I was sick of looking at all the boilerplate cuda code for copying data to the device so I wrote this wrapper function:

```
void allocateAndCopyToDevice(void* device_array, const void* host_array, const size_t &count)
{
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&device_array, count));  
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(device_array, host_array, count, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
}
```

but for some reason this resulted in an out of bounds memory access whenever using an array initialized in this way. The initialization code that I used looked like this:

```
cuDoubleComplex *d_cmplx;
allocateAndCopyToDevice(d_cmplx,cmplx,size*sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
```

Could anyone explain why this doesn't work?

---

After seeing immibis's comment I realized that cudaMalloc expects a pointer to a pointer, so instead I'm passing by value the pointer to the pointer:

```
void allocateAndCopyToDevice(void** device_array, const void* host_array, const size_t &count)
{
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(device_array, count));  
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(*device_array, host_array, count, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
}
```

and the initialization now looks like this:

```
cuDoubleComplex *d_cmplx;
allocateAndCopyToDevice((void **)&d_cmplx,cmplx,size*sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
```

It works, but I'm still wondering if there is a better way of doing this? How do other people handle memory transfers in cuda code?

Comment: Hint: why does `void f(int x) {x = 42;} int main() {int j; f(j); printf("%d\n", j); return 0;}` not print 42?

Comment: @immibis: It might, because `j` is not initialised.

Comment: *I wasn't actually passing the pointer by reference.* -- You're still not passing the pointer by reference.  You're still passing by value, but that value happens to be a `void**` instead of the (erroneous) `void*`.  Passing by reference in C++ means exactly that -- passing a reference (a reference is not a pointer).

Comment: Not really related to CUDA

Comment: C does not allow pass by reference, only by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like

```
template <typename T>
T* allocateAndCopyToDevice(const T* host_array, std::size_t count)
{
    // some static_assert for allowed types: pod and built-in.
    T* device_array = nullptr;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&device_array, count * sizeof(T)));  
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(device_array, host_array, count * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    return device_array;
}
```

and use it:

```
cuDoubleComplex *d_cmplx = allocateAndCopyToDevice(cmplx, size);
```

Comment: this is way better than what I have. Why do you need to use a nullptr though?

Comment: I prefer to always initialize variables.